# How pass the request object in inclusion tag?

Tags: python, django, django-context

I am using django 1.5

I want pass the request object to my inclusion tag, however get a error, Key Error.

My view is:

```
class IglesiaCreateView(CreateView):
     model = Iglesia
     template_name = 'iglesia/iglesia_form.html'
     success_url = reverse_lazy('iglesia_list')
     form_class = IglesiaForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(IglesiaCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs
```

My form is:

```
class IglesiaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Iglesia
        fields = ('nombre', 'principal', 'parroquia')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(IglesiaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        parroquia = self.request.session.get('parroquia')
        self.fields['parroquia'].queryset = Parroquia.objects.filter(pk=parroquia.pk)
        self.fields['parroquia'].empty_label = None
```

My inclusion tag is:

```
from myapp.forms import IglesiaForm
@register.inclusion_tag('includes/iglesia_ajax_form.html', takes_context=True)
    def iglesia_ajax(context):
    request = context['request']
    form_iglesia = IglesiaForm()
    ctx = {'form_iglesia': form_iglesia}
    return ctx
```

I have a error:

```
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 'request'
```

**EDIT:**

Problem solved

I add in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS the follow: 'django.core.context_processors.request'.

And change:

```
form_iglesia = IglesiaForm()
```

to:

```
form_iglesia = IglesiaForm(request=request)
```

**Thanks for your help**

Comment: I don't see the relationship between your tag and the ModelForm your showed. Please make it clear.

Comment: I am using in my inclusion tag: form_iglesia = IglesiaForm()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line

```
form_iglesia = IglesiaForm()
```

to:

```
form_iglesia = IglesiaForm(request=request)
```

See if that works.

Comment: I just added in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS the following: 'django.core.context_processors.request', and it worked. Did it work?. 
This line of code affects the behavior of my app?

Comment: this line of code adds the request variable to every context of every template. I thought you had done this already. Sorry.